# Passing default values in Laravel 4 route like in ZF2

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

In ZF2 I am able to create a route as such:

```
'member-login-after-expired-session' => array(
    'type'     => 'segment',
    'options'  =>  array(
        'route'    =>  '/loginAgain',
        'defaults' =>  array(
            'controller' => 'Foo\Controller\Bar',   
            'action'     => 'someMethod',
            'activity'   => 'login',
            'reason'     => 'expired-session',
),),),
```

This route can be accessed at domain.com/loginAgain and will pass two parameters "activity" and "reason" **without them being in the url**. I can access these parameters, and any others, within the allotted zf2 controller via:

```
$this->params('activity')
$this->params('reason')
```

How can I accomplish this in Laravel 4.2?

So far, the documentation I've read at (http://laravel.com/docs/routing) indicates that all parameters have to be passed via the actual url and that's not what I want. I've tried this:

```
Route::get
(
    '/loginAgain',
    array
    (
        'as'        =>  'loginAgain',
        'uses'      =>  'BarController@someMethod',
    ),
    array
    (
        'activity'  =>  'login',
        'reason'    =>  'expired-session',
    )
)
```

with the accompanying controller as this:

```
class BarController extends BaseController
{
    public function someMethod($activity, $reason)
    {
        echo $activity;
        echo $reason;
     ...
```

However, I get missing argument errors. What exactly should I be doing artisans?

Comment: This has nothing to do with zf2, removing the tag as zf2 users won't be able to answer this Laravel question.

Comment: Wouldn't a zf2 coder who also has experience with laravel be able to answer this question? Especially since the original route is specific to zf2 and the desired route is specific to laravel 4?

Comment: Well, it is like "hey I found a cool feature in X, can I do this in Y". The point is you need Y experts, not X. You explain the routing feature pretty well for Laravel users, so they are able to understand your question :)

Comment: I need Y experts that have experience in X. The original route structure is not generic, it's X specific. The desired route structure is hopefully Y specific. I'm trying to avoid a situation where a potential answer is excluded because only Y answers were allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly - this would work

```
Route::get('/login/{param1}/{param2}', ['uses' => 'BarController @someMethod']);
Route::get('/login',  ['uses' => 'BarController @otherMethod']);
```

Then in your controller I would do

```
class BarController extends BaseController
{
    public function someMethod($activity, $reason)
    {
        echo $activity;
        echo $reason;
        ...
    }


    public function otherMethod()
    {
        return $this->someMethod('default1', 'default2');
    }
```

**OR this might work (havent tested)**

```
Route::get('/login/{param1}/{param2}', ['uses' => 'BarController @someMethod']);
Route::get('/login',  ['uses' => 'BarController @someMethod']);
```

and then in your controller

```
class BarController extends BaseController
{
    public function someMethod($activity = 'default1', $reason = 'default2')
    {
        echo $activity;
        echo $reason;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This definitely works and get's the job done which is the point. It's not specific to Laravel's routing structure but still clean. I added properties to the class and "set" them with the otherMethod call.